# Noise Cancelling on the AirPods Pro

Tags: audio, airpods

I bought myself a new pair of AirPod Pros and I am trying to decide if they are defective or if I was expecting too much of the noise-cancelling feature.

When I have the AirPods in noise-cancelling mode and I snap my fingers I can hear the snap. I can also hear people talking around me. (The volume of the talking goes down, but I can still hear people talk) Is that normal?

Stuff I have checked:

- I have done the ear tip fittest and I get a good seal result on both
  ears.
- I have Switched to transparency and off mode and back to the
  noise-cancelling mode and I can still hear my fingers snap in
  noise-cancelling mode.
- I have (obviously)turned it off and on again.    Same result.

Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Things like this are difficult to diagnose without actual access to the hardware. Did you check out reviews and experience reports others posted in the last months?

Comment: I did. Am pretty sure I watched every review of the thing on Youtube. It looked like the ANC should, at least, block out people talking around me.

Comment: In my experience with both the AirPod pro’s and Bose qc35’s, I need to play music as well to help drown out outside noise. I don’t think it’s reasonable to expect complete silence from the ANC.